# How can I extract specific data points from a wide-formatted text file in R?

Tags: r

I have datasheets with multiple measurements that look like the following:

```
FILE    DATE    TIME    LOC     QUAD    LAI     SEL DIFN    MTA SEM SMP
20  20210805    08:38:32    H       1161    2.80    0.68    0.145   49. 8.  4

ANGLES  7.000   23.00   38.00   53.00   68.00
CNTCT#  1.969   1.517   0.981   1.579   1.386
STDDEV  1.632   1.051   0.596   0.904   0.379
DISTS   1.008   1.087   1.270   1.662   2.670
GAPS    0.137   0.192   0.288   0.073   0.025

A     1 08:38:40    31.66   33.63   34.59   39.13   55.86
1     2 08:38:40    -5.0e-006
B     3 08:38:48    25.74   20.71   15.03   2.584   1.716
B     4 08:38:55    0.344   1.107   2.730   0.285   0.265
B     5 08:39:02    3.211   5.105   13.01   4.828   1.943
B     6 08:39:10    8.423   22.91   48.77   16.34   3.572
B     7 08:39:19    12.58   14.90   18.34   18.26   4.125
```

I would like to read the entire datasheet and extract the values for 'QUAD' and 'LAI' only. For example, for the data above I would only be extracting a QUAD of 1161 and an LAI of 2.80.

In the past the datasheets were formatted as long data, and I was able to use the following code:

```
library(stringr)
QUAD <- as.numeric(str_trim(str_extract(data, "(?m)(?<=^QUAD).*$")))
LAI <- as.numeric(str_trim(str_extract(data, "(?m)(?<=^LAI).*$")))

data_extract <- data.frame(
 QUAD = QUAD[!is.na(QUAD)],
 LAI = LAI[!is.na(LAI)]
)
data_extract
```

Unfortunately, this does not work because of the wide formatting in the current datasheet. Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What about reformatting the data to long format by using tidyr::pivot_longer() ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that function and am having trouble applying it to the text dataset. Do you mind elaborating on how I can use that? Thanks for the helpful response

Comment: Please look into this https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html 

In case you still find difficulty in applying it, it would be much better if you provide your dataset in a reproducible example.